Retrieve Daily Metrics for Facebook Posts, Videos, and Reels Using Graph API
Body:
I need to retrieve all daily metrics (e.g., impressions, reactions, video views) for my Facebook posts, videos, reels, etc., starting from their creation date. However, using Graph API v20.0 or higher, I only receive cumulative or incorrect data instead of individual daily values.
Here is what I’ve tried so far:

Refreshing the Access Token:
I've implemented token refresh logic to ensure a valid access token is always available.

Fetching Metrics Daily:
I request metrics using the insights endpoint with period=day. However, the results seem cumulative or incomplete.


Code Snippets:
1. Token Refresh Logic
The function below refreshes the token and saves it locally.
import requests
from config import ACCESS_TOKEN, API_VERSION, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET

def refresh_access_token():
    """Refresh the access token to get a new long-lived token."""
    refresh_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{API_VERSION}/oauth/access_token"
    params = {
        'grant_type': 'fb_exchange_token',
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'fb_exchange_token': ACCESS_TOKEN,
    }

    response = requests.get(refresh_url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        new_access_token = data.get('access_token')
        if new_access_token:
            print("New token obtained:", new_access_token)
            with open('access_token.txt', 'w') as token_file:
                token_file.write(new_access_token)
            return new_access_token
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error refreshing token: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

2. Fetch Daily Metrics for a Post
I fetch metrics using period=day, but the data is cumulative:
def fetch_daily_metrics(post_id, metrics, start_date, end_date):
    token = get_access_token()
    insights_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/{post_id}/insights"
    params = {
        'metric': ','.join(metrics),
        'access_token': token,
        'period': 'day',
        'since': start_date,
        'until': end_date,
    }

    response = requests.get(insights_url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get('data', [])
    else:
        print(f"Error fetching metrics: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)
        return None

3. Processing Metrics into Google Sheets
I use this to upload metrics into Google Sheets for analysis:
import pandas as pd
from google_sheets import upload_to_google_sheets

def process_and_upload_metrics(metrics_data):
    rows = []
    for metric in metrics_data:
        name = metric['name']
        for value in metric.get('values', []):
            rows.append({'Date': value['end_time'], 'Metric': name, 'Value': value['value']})

    df = pd.DataFrame(rows).pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Metric', values='Value').reset_index()
    upload_to_google_sheets(df, "Facebook Insights", "Daily Metrics")

Current Problems:

Metrics are cumulative:
I expected daily values but received cumulative ones. How can I ensure the API provides individual daily values?

Data mismatch:
Some metrics appear inconsistent with the Facebook UI insights.

API Version:
I’ve tested API versions from v15.0 to v21.0. Which version is recommended for daily metrics?


Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Tags:
[facebook-graph-api] [python] [google-sheets] [facebook-api]
Links:
Here’s the documentation I’ve been following.
Thank you for your help! 
